# How to change the color of textview backgrounds when swiped?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I am developing an android word search app and I have dynamically created a `tablelayout` with `textviews` on it to hold each letters. I want to change the background color of those `textviews` when the user's finger swipe on the letter grid.

This is the code for the table layout:

```
public void createGrid(char[][] input) {
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rl);
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    table.setTag(1);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "kg.ttf");
    int j;



    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        LinearLayout rowLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        rowLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        rowLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        final TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        for (j = 0; j < input.length; j++) {
            final TextView text = new TextView(this);
            Character temp = input[i][j];
            text.setTag(i);
            text.setText(temp.toString());
            text.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
            text.setTag(i);
            text.setTextSize(txtSize);
            text.setTypeface(font);
            text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#c03768b7"));
                    ((TextView)view).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                }
            });
            row.addView(text);
            row.getChildAt(j);

        }
        table.addView(row);

    }
  }
```

And as you can see, I assigned `OnClickListeners` on each `TextViews`. But I want a hassle-free highlighting so, is there a way to change that to swiping and not clicking each `textviews`?

Any comments, answers, and suggestions is very much appreciated.

EDIT:

What I'm trying to do is change the color of the letters in text as the text is swiped.

Comment: Are you trying to change the color of letters in text as the text is swiped?

Comment: @Gboy... Please check the answer and let me knw the situation

Comment: @Superman - yes. That is what I'm trying to do

Comment: @Athul sorry for the late response. I'm gonna try this now and will tell you if it works for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Athul I tried the answer but it seems like only one textview is affected by that code and only shows a toast of what the direction of the swipe is. I tried to put the: `view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#c03768b7"));
                    ((TextView)view).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);` on the if else statement but that doesn't work either.

Comment: please test the latest update.....

Comment: @Athul Thank you very much for updating your answer. But that code also affects only one textview. What I really want is to change the bg color of other textviews affected by the swipe. Like if you swipe from textview1 to textview2 that is on the left, those two textviews' bg color will be changed.

Comment: you mean both the textview color need to be changed

Comment: @Athul yes that is what i want to happen

Answer (score 0):

Detect the Swipe like mentioned below and implement the function to change the color of textview background

```
     text.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    switch (event.getAction()) {

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            x1 = event.getX();
                            y1 = event.getY();
                            t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            return true;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            x2 = event.getX();
                            y2 = event.getY();
                            t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

                            if (x1 > x2) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Left swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                // Insert your code to change the color of the textview background.
                  v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#c03768b7")); 
                            } else if (x2 > x1) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Right swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#c03768b7")); 
                               // Insert your code to change the color of the textview background.

                            } 


                            return true;
                    }

                    return false;
                }
```

Comment: Change backgorund using this txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

Comment: Instead of adding color like this...u can create an array and use a function t =o change the color of background using array index number in the function

Comment: only if u want the background to change with multiple number of colors